# Ffmpeg Multiple Crop

Tags: ffmpeg, crop

How can I make crop in and out from 3 to 3 seconds to a video.
for Exemple:

The First 3 sec Of the video to be original,

The next 3 sec of the video to be CROP `crop=iw-684:ih-516,scale=1280:720`

The next 3 sec Of the video to be original,

The next 3 sec of the video to be CROP `crop=iw-684:ih-516,scale=1280:720`

**so on, until the end of the video**
Please Help Me

Comment: Is the original video 1280x720?

Comment: yes. Can you help me please ?